# why we need to register providers in web.config?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, membership-provider

when working with Asp.net MVC. Why we need to register membership provider in the web.config file ?

Comment: You don't need to register any providers in web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Membership providers provide the interface between Microsoft ASP.NET's membership service and membership data sources.

The fundamental job of a membership provider is to manage the data regarding a site's registered users, and to provide methods for creating users, deleting users, verifying login credentials, changing passwords, and so on. The Microsoft .NET Framework's System.Web.Security namespace includes a class named MembershipUser that defines the basic attributes of a membership user, and that a membership provider uses to represent individual users.

You willhave more information here [Membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478949.aspx)

Thanks